# Can I detect the orientation of an image without saving it to file?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am trying to build a receipt scanning Android app and the way that I am handling really long receipts is to take multiple pictures and compile them into one long image. I tried doing image stitching with opencv but I ran into too many memory issues on older devices.

I am now running into the issue that with certain devices, specifically the Samsung Galaxy Player and Samsung Galaxy Tab 2, the preview and image capture orientation are not correct. The receipt needs to be scanned in portrait mode.

I have tried using this code to rotate the preview: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29
I added a line of code that rotates the camera by the same value that it rotates the preview. 
On the Galaxy Player, this makes the preview display as still rotated but now flipped. The pictures that it returns are still rotated as if the camera was not rotated.
On the Galaxy Tab the preview displays correctly but the image that it creates is upside down.

Is there a way to detect the top and bottom of the image without saving it to file and getting the EXIF? Would that even make a difference on these devices or is there a deeper issue with those devices?

Thanks!